# Mock a Drawable with Mockito and Android

Tags: java, android, mocking, mockito, tdd

How can I mock a Drawable? I have tried this code. It doesn't compile yet:

```
@Test
public void readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
    Simulation myObjectUnderTest = new Simulation();
    when(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(Resources.getSystem()));
    when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(new Place("blaha", mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)));
    WalkingPerson myObjectUnderTest2 = new WalkingPerson(myObjectUnderTest, mock(AdventureWorld.class), "blaha", 2, mActivity);
    String result2 = myObjectUnderTest2.getHelloWorldString();
    assertThat(result2, is(FAKE_STRING));
}
```

I don't know how to mock the drawable. The problem is this statement

`when(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(Resources.getSystem()));`

I also try the following

```
package dev.game.adventure;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AdventureTest {

    private static final String FAKE_STRING = "HELLO WORLD";

    @Mock
    Simulation engine;

    @Mock
    AdventureWorld mWorld;

    @Mock
    FullscreenActivity mActivity;

    @Mock
    Drawable mDrawable;


    @Test
    public void readStringFromContext_LocalizedString() {
        Simulation myObjectUnderTest = new Simulation();
        when(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
        when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(new Place("blaha", mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)));
        WalkingPerson myObjectUnderTest2 = new WalkingPerson(myObjectUnderTest, mock(AdventureWorld.class), "blaha", 2, mActivity);
        String result2 = myObjectUnderTest2.getHelloWorldString();
        assertThat(result2, is(FAKE_STRING));
    }


    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        assertEquals("dev.game.adventure", appContext.getPackageName());

    }


}
```

But I get this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(int)' on a null object reference
at dev.game.adventure.AdventureTest.readStringFromContext_LocalizedString(AdventureTest.java:53)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2074)
```

Update. It still doesn't work. I'm just wasting my time.

```
package dev.game.adventure;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AdventureTest {

    private static final String FAKE_STRING = "HELLO WORLD";

    @Mock
    Simulation engine;

    @Mock
    AdventureWorld mWorld;

    @Mock
    FullscreenActivity mActivity;

    @Mock
    Drawable mDrawable;


    @Mock
    Resources mResources;


    @Mock
    Place mPlace;

    @Test
   // @Ignore
    public void readStringFromCowntext_LocalizedString() {
        Simulation myObjectUnderTest = new Simulation();
        when(mResources.getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
        when(mActivity.getResources()).thenReturn(mResources);
        when(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.dungeon)).thenReturn(mDrawable);
        when(mWorld.defaultPlace()).thenReturn(mPlace);
        WalkingPerson myObjectUnderTest2 = new WalkingPerson(myObjectUnderTest, mock(AdventureWorld.class), "blaha", 2, mActivity);
        String result2 = myObjectUnderTest2.getHelloWorldString();
        assertThat(result2, is(FAKE_STRING));
    }


    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        assertEquals("dev.game.adventure", appContext.getPackageName());

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mock mActivity but you don't specify what should happen when calling the getResources() method on this mock. Therefore this method returns null and you run into the NPE.

In order to make it work, you need to return a mock object for the getResources() method as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. My tests are progressing now.

Comment: how to mocking object resources?